# Автоматически создавать очереди rabbitmq

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq

Возьмем строчку [из документации к Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching):

```
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->onQueue('processing');
```

Тут создается задача ProcessPodcast, и помещается в очередь `processing`. Теперь представим, что используется драйвер `rabbitmq`, а очереди `processing` в Rabbitmq нет. Задача не будет выполнена.

**Первый вариант**

Казалось бы, нужно зайти в админку кролика и добавить эту очередь. Но с точки зрения CI/CD так делать неправильно.

**Второй вариант**

Ладно, создадим миграцию (выполняется один раз) и в нее пропишем создание очереди. Но если кролик будет пересоздан с нуля, очередь пропадет.

**Третий вариант**

Перед отправкой сообщения в очередь будем ее создавать:

```
RabbitHelper::createAndBindQueue('processing'); // тут создаем очередь
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->onQueue('processing');
```

Но это ужасно, потому что везде придется прописывать дополнительную строчку кода. А если проект перейдет на Redis, эту строчку придется выпиливать. Неудачно решение.

Вот пожелания.

1. Очереди могут потеряться, и нужно их каким-то образом автоматически пересоздавать
2. Если Rabbitmq не используется (например, phpunit тесты), очереди создавать не нужно
3. Не хочется засорять код конструкциями типа `RabbitHelper::createAndBindQueue()`

Итак, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Используйте [сторонний драйвер](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) или создайте свой?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov как это может помочь? И этот пакет уже используется, работает вместе с horizon.

Comment: Не видя всего кода, скажу чтобы взяли 3 вариант. Выделите работу с подкастами в отдельный сервис "PodcastService" можете да же создать фасад. Сервис может возвращать репозиторий или ещё какую-то логику с помощью методов, а не голые методы в нём (вспоминаем про разделение логики и ответственности). И будет метод sendToQueue(Podcast $podcast). в результате в нём будут данные две строчки, НО первую строчку просто оберните в if (Queue::getConnectionName() === 'rabbitMQ') ... В результате Вам не надо добавлять везде по 2 строчки, а всего одну PodcastService::sendToQueue($podcast). Это Вы хотели?

Comment: Это неудачное решение. Почему? На каждую новую задачу придется делать такую обертку.

Comment: ну ок, я описал для конкретного случая связанного с подкастами. Сделайте абстрактный хелпер. Который будет работать со всеми типами задач, создавать удалять и т.д. `Dispatcher::sendToQueue(new ProcessPodcast($podcast), 'queue-name')`. Внутри же метода будет sendToQueue(Job $job, string $queueName) и далее `ProcessPodcast::dispatch` заменяете на `dispatch($job)->onQueue($queueName)`. Первая строка остаётся такой же, только `$queueName` подставите на место просто слова